# No token returned with Reddit OAuth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, reddit

I'm having trouble getting the tokens back from Reddit's Oauth. I'm running a node.js backend with a React front end. What I get back from Reddit when I try to exchange the code for a bearer token using `node-fetch`, all I get is just a this below:

`"url": "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
"status": 200,
"statusText": "OK",
...`

There's more there but there's no field in the body or anywhere else that holds the access token or refresh token.

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that appears to be a deprecated endpoint, i dont see anywhere on https://www.reddit.com/dev/api

try using passport: https://github.com/slotos/passport-reddit. it will work.